# Boot from a VHD created by VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vhd

I have used VirtualBox to create a VM, and installed the latest Windows 8 Consumer Preview on it.

I have a .VHD file with the OS installed.

I am wondering, since Windows 7 supports boot from a VHD file, whether it is possible to simply create a new boot option using thid VHD file and boot of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.  Windows 7 supports boot from VHD.  There are two blog posts I've seen on this.

One from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx) and this [one](http://ericdboyd.com/2012/03/02/how-to-install-windows-8-with-native-boot-to-vhd)

Since you already have the vhd, you only need to run the Bcdedit command .

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a Linux VHD as well as a Windows VHD?

Comment: It is my understanding that only Windows OS is supported in VHD boot.  However, i see no mention of that in this MS post on the topic: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825689.aspx